# Split image with top navigation drawer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to have a top navigation sit on top of an image on my homepage. When you click on one of the navigation buttons, it opens a drawer with other navigation items, and pushed the rest of the content down. This would need to split the homepage background image where the navigation drawer opens.

You can see a working example of exactly what I am talking about here: https://squareup.com/.

Click on "Business Types" or "Products" to see the desired effect.

How can I do something similar to this. Does anyone have any pointers or things to look into?

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Lazerbrains

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I wasn't even sure how to approach it, that is why I asked the question. I was looking for some direction, which I got from RickT. And I only posted here after I really couldn't find much of anything about this on Google. Thanks for the "Message Board 101" lesson. That really helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create 3 divs, one for the menu, one for the hidden content and one that sits just below it, we'll call 'banner'.

On the menu AND the 'banner' set the same background image.  Then using the css `background-postion` property, set the menu to `background-postion: top;` and the banner should be `background-position: negative HeightOfYourMenu;`

If you use the jQuery .slideDown method for the hidden content, you should get the effect you want.

So something like:

```
.menu {
  background-image: url(YourBgPath);
  background-position: top;
  height: 100px;
}

.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}

.banner {
  background-image: url(YourBgPath);
  background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

Comment: Oh. Well that makes perfect sense. I think I was going about it all wrong and making it far too difficult. I will give that a go and let you know how it turns out.